# Error Code: 1242 Subquery returns more than 1 row mysql

Tags: mysql

I am trying select the cost based on destination(DEST). If the cost not exist for country, then i have to find for continent, if the cost not exist for continent also, then i have select based on others(destination).

```
SELECT SUM(CD.COST+CW.COST) AS TOTAL_COST 
FROM SHIP_COST_BY_DEST CD 
INNER JOIN SHIP_COST_BY_WEIGHT CW
ON CD.PROD_CODE = CW.PROD_CODE
WHERE IF((SELECT UPPER(CD.DEST) FROM SHIP_COST_BY_DEST),
(UPPER(CD.DEST) = UPPER('Others')),
(IF((SELECT UPPER(CD.DEST) FROM SHIP_COST_BY_DEST 
WHERE UPPER(CD.DEST)=UPPER('India')),
UPPER(CD.DEST) = UPPER('India'),'Asia')))
```

Could any one help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's an awfully complex WHERE clause - it will be a nightmare to maintain.  But the problem is that one of your subqueries (The selects inside the parentheses) is returning multiple values and logic doesn't permit that.  The easiest thing for you to do (since I don't have your data) is to run each of those subqueries separately and see which returns multiple values, and see if it logically makes sense at that place.

For example, you can't say

```
Name = (SELECT Name FROM AllCustomers)
```

because the name can't EQUAL all those names at once.  You can, however, say

```
Name IN (SELECT Name FROM AllCustomers)
```

because that gives you a list of possibilities for it to be IN.  Also, you need to make sure that not only are all of your subqueries only returning one answer if appropriate NOW, but that they can ONLY return one answer, or you'll end up with a problem in production when the data is different from what you tested with.

Comment: @Naveen Glad I could help!  Please mark this answer as the correct answer so other StackOverflow people won't bother trying to answer it - thanks!